# JQL Many to Many select where :item not in items

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

When we have this structure:

```
@Entity
public class A {

....

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    public Set<B> getB() {
        return b;
    }
```

and

```
@Entity
public class B {

...

    @ManyToMany
    public Set<A> getA() {
        return a;
    }
```

How we can query entity A for getting rows where given b value is not in `Set<B>`? I mean, get all A, which don't have given b in their `Set<B>`.

I was trying this solutions:

```
from A where :bInstance not in b
```

and

```
select a from A a where a not in (b.a from B b where b.name = :name)
```

and

```
select a from A a where a not exists (b.a from B b where b.name = :name)
```

but with no luck.

I know I can do it with querying all A and then iterate it and filter, but I would like do it without querying all rows in db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way, with the `member of` operator:

```
select a from A a where :bInstance not member of a.b
```